# Nivo Slider - Hide thumbnails if there is only one image and prevent slideshow transitions

Tags: nivo-slider

I am using the Nivo Slider for the first time and it is absolutely awesome however I do have a couple of issues.

I have it integrated within a CMS and this allows the user to add up to 5 images.

If there is only one image however, I would like to just hide the thumbnails and stop any transitions, as in sliding the same image in again and again.

Now is this something I would do with JQuery or should I be editing the 'jquery.nivo.slider.js' file?  Or is it potentially something I could potentially accomplis in both?

I guess I am looking to do something like:

```
if images < 1 {
 transition = false;
 thumbnails = hide;
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense.

Thanks for your time and help.

**UPDATE**

Okay so I have managed to hide the thumbnails if there is only one image by adding the following to the jquery.nivo.slider.js file:

```
if (vars.totalSlides < 2)
{
 $('.nivo-controlNav').remove();
}
```

I now want to be able to change one of the settings in the following piece of code based on the same rule but am not sure how to do this:

```
$.fn.nivoSlider.defaults = {
    pauseOnHover: 'false',
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the config array and initialize the slider like this:

```
// nivo config array
var nivoConfig = {
    slices: 30, // For slice animations
    boxCols: 16, // For box animations
    // put all your init config here but exclude 'effects'
}

if(imagesCount < 2) {
    nivoConfig['effects'] = 'none';
} else {
  nivoConfig['effects'] = 'random';
}

$('#slider').nivoSlider(nivoConfig);
```

Try it out, it should work in a way like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem; Johnny's code worked perfectly, but I wanted to elaborate for people who may be having problems with this.  You'll want to insert:

```
 if (vars.totalSlides < 2) {
    $('.nivo-controlNav').remove();
}
```

on or around line 158 in the jquery.nivo.slider.js file (within the if(settings.controlNav) {} conditional).  Otherwise it won't work.